# How to display multiple records by same id?

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have 2 tables, book and user. Both tables have ids to connect them together. I wanted to display the image of the books that the user adds. I did a query to match the relevant ids and this is the output.

```
  id |   user_name    |   image
 ------------------------------------
 6   |   d            |  image.png
 ------------------------------------
 3   |   bb           |   tfos.jpg
 ------------------------------------
 6   |   d            |   the-business-plan.jpg
------------------------------------
 3   |   bb           |   front-page.jpg
------------------------------------
```

The issue now is when I logged in as the user 'd' only one image was displayed which is 'image.png' whereas as seen 'd' has 2 records.

these are the relevant codes that I put as for now:

```
$query3 = "SELECT * FROM user, book WHERE user_name='$entered_username' AND book.id = user.id ";
$result3 = mysqli_query($link, $query3) or die(mysqli_error($link));
if (mysqli_num_rows($result3) != 0) {
$rowz = mysqli_fetch_array($result3);
} else { //record not found
echo "No record found";
}
```

In html to display:

```
      <div class="panel panel-default"><div class="panel-heading"><i>Books</i> youadd</div><div class="panel-body"> <img width="150"src="images/<?php echo $rowz['image']; ?>"/></div></div>
```

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Use a loop to fetch results**

```
<?php
while($rowz = mysqli_fetch_array($result3))
{
?>
<!-- fetch result here, thus you get 2 results -->
 <div class="panel panel-default"><div class="panel-heading"><i>Books</i> youadd</div><div class="panel-body"> <img width="150"src="images/<?php echo $rowz['image']; ?>"/>
<?php
}
?>
```